# How to get the RecordMetadata of a produced message?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I want to access and log in my Flink application the RecordMetadata of the produced message. Is there somehow a possibly to get the offset/partition of the produced message with the usage of `org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer`?

Answer (score 0):

The RecordMetadata is logged on failures, but I don't believe it is possible (using Flink's public API) to register a callback for receiving it.